# What should I do about bad questions like this one?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331643/css-check-which-option-is-selected#comment46852588_29331643

This kind of questions may be interpreted as a lack of effort to try to find the answer, but maybe he just don't know anything about Javascript.

In any case, I'd like to help him. Is it OK that I edit his question to something like "how to check which option is selected with jQuery" or something like that, or should I just limit myself to advice him to learn Javascript and jQuery?

I hope this question will help in similar situations in the future.

Comment: If you can infer a deep insight from two lines of text in the question then, godspeed, nobody else could and nobody else cared.  You can basically make it anything you want it to be and nobody will slow you down.  There's another million of those btw.

Comment: "No, you can't do that with pure CSS. Here's how you can do it using JavaScript. <example>" seems like a perfectly reasonable answer to that question.

Comment: My personal feeling on the question in...question is that it's not "bad" per se; there are reasonable answers that do involve JavaScript.  It's not worthy of closure as it's very much on topic and clear as too what's being asked, but I have a strong hunch that a question *like* this has been asked at some point before, or the solution has been highlighted in previous answers.  May be a good thing to look for a duplicate on.

Comment: Good point. It seems the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer the question in general.

**If you can fix the question**; that is, the question has **enough information** present to be on topic in either the question body, or has some information added in through comments, then by all means do so.  This means adding more relevant tags if need be, and cleaning up the grammar.  If you can do this, **please** do - that'd help out a lot.

**If you cannot fix the question**; that is, the question **lacks sufficient detail** to remain on-topic without extensive information from the OP, then downvote and/or vote to <s>close</s> put on hold as appropriate.  If it's incomplete, then putting it on hold is a good way to get the OP's attention to come back and finish filling in details while preventing half-informed answers from materializing.

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks. My opinion is that, even if it lacks effort and/or knowledge proof, he explained his problem well enough to being able to give him some relevant answer.

Comment: "Knowledge proof" is one of those things I feel one should get away from when judging questions and their answerability.   If they knew enough about the subject they were asking about, they wouldn't have to ask.  In my mind, they made an effort and someone should be able to work with what they've got from there.

Comment: I think so too. I wandered because it was 3 times downvoted, and didn't seem to meet the requirements described in SO rules.

Comment: @SebasSBM: other people downvoting a question does not necessarily have to change whether you answer it or not. At present you may even answer questions that you know are firmly off-topic, since there is no sanction against doing so (other than, perhaps, a minor risk of downvotes). However, this question doesn't show any effort, and a good proportion of readers would generally prefer to downvote/close/ignore, so as not to feed a potential help vampire.